# Symfony2 Controller message with html tag

Tags: php, html, symfony, controller

I have a problem in a controller with a message when i send an invite email with success.

I have this code:

```
$mail_success = $trans->trans('mail.success',array( "%email%"=>$email),'messages',$locale );
                $this->addFlash("message", $mail_success);
```

In a page .yml for the translations i have a message like this:

```
mail.success : "%email%, send with success"
```

But i would print on my page a message with a class for edit the style, now i get this:

```
<div>email@email.com, send with success </div>
```

I would this result for example:
    email@email.com, send with success

Where the controller get this tag ?? How can i do for get the result i want??
Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: so you want to get rid of the <div></div> tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DIV tag appears because your (Twig) template fetching the flash messages to render them is placing each message in a DIV tag.

This is actually a sensible way to do it as the flash bag could contain more than one message to be shown. If you didn't put each message in such a block tag then each flash message would appear concatenated into a single message.

Comment: How can i do for fix a class in the div tag?? @Adambean

Comment: If you want to give the DIV a class you need to do it in the template file that is rendering the flash messages. You will have already implemented this in one of your templates somewhere, probably a shared / layout template file.